# Algebraic multiplicity

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

Give the matrix A:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

How can I find the algebraic multiplicity of this polynomial?

$-λ^3 + λ^2 + 8λ - 12$

Knowing that the eigenvalues of the matrix are $2, 2, -3$?

I know I have to substitute the eigenvalues in the polynomial but I can't understand what is the algebraic multiplicity.

How do I find the base for each eigenspace?

Comment: I guess the uspoken hypothesis is that $\lambda\in\Bbb C^{3\times 3}$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It's a 3x3 matrix in real numbers

Comment: What's the algebraic multiplicity of a *polynomial*?

Comment: Do you have the matrix that gave you that characteristic polynomial?

Comment: A lot of times my teacher would refer to a multiplicity as for the root 2 which would be 2 (you have two 2's). As if in you do not have to plug in $λ_1=2$ and then a separate case when $λ_2=2$, for solving the differential eqn. You plug in only one distinct root every time, rref the matrix to determine the null space for your $A-λ I$, and then go forth from there for only two cases, because you only have two distinct roots.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're looking for the algebraic multiplicity of the *polynomial*, but of its *roots*; no?

> How can I find the algebraic multiplicity of this polynomial?
>
> $-λ^3 + λ^2 + 8λ - 12$
>
> Knowing that the eigenvalues of the matrix are $2, 2, -3$?

And if this is given, then you already know the multiplicities... If not, it is precisely because:
$$-λ^3 + λ^2 + 8λ - 12 = -\left( \lambda-\color{green}{2} \right)^\color{blue}{2} \left(\lambda-(\color{red}{-3})\right)^\color{purple}{1}$$
that we say that the root $\lambda = \color{green}{2}$ has algebraic multiplicity $\color{blue}{2}$ and the root $\lambda = \color{red}{-3}$ has algebraic multiplicity $\color{purple}{1}$.

In general, we say that $x=\color{green}{a}$ is a root with **algebraic multiplicity** $\color{blue}{k}$ of a polynomial $p(x)$, if there exists a polynomial $q(x)$ such that $p(x) = (x-\color{green}{a})^\color{blue}{k}q(x)$ with $q(\color{green}{a}) \ne 0$.

---

*Added after comment.*

> I don't know how to transform $-λ^3 + λ^2 + 8λ - 12$ into a polynomial with brackets

That's a different question; you should look up how to *factor a polynomial*. It's possible you can avoid having to do this by simplifying the determinant $\det\left(A-\lambda I_n\right)$ in a different way. If you do end up with this cubic polynomial; you can use methods like [Horner's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Now that you've given $A$, it is indeed easy to avoid having to factor a cubic polynomial to find its eigenvalues and corresponding algebraic multiplicities; because:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
    2-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0-\lambda & 2 \\
    0 & 3 & -1-\lambda \\
    \end{vmatrix}=\left(2-\lambda\right)\begin{vmatrix}
     0-\lambda & 2 \\
     3 & -1-\lambda \\
    \end{vmatrix}=\ldots$$

Comment: I don't know how to transform $−λ^3+λ^2+8λ−12$ into a polynomial with brackets

Comment: That's a different question then! I'll add a part to my answer.

Comment: 2 has algebraic multiplicity of 2 because there are two eigenvalues that are 2?

Comment: It has algebraic multiplicity of 2 because it is a _double root_ of the characteristic polynomial. If you want, you could also say it's a _double eigenvalue_, although you should be careful not to get the algebraic and geometric multiplicity mixed up. I would say this matrix only has 2 (distinct) eigenvalues; but that's a matter of convention/preference.

Comment: Is $−λ^3+λ^2+8λ−12=0$ equal to $(λ-2)(λ+3)(λ-2)=0$ ?

Comment: If you mean _equivalent_ (in the sense that both polynomial equations have the same solutions), then yes. Note however that the left-hand sides are not _equal_, but _opposite_.

Comment: How can I find a base for each autospace of A?

Comment: John; the comment section isn't meant for elaborate (additional) questions - it's better to either update your initial question and include all aspects, or to start a new question. Please provide the full context, like giving the matrix $A$.

Comment: I added the matrix A in the post